# Error in !implicit_figures : invalid argument type

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, knitr

After updating R studio this morning it seems my R markdown file is no longer working, with the following error coming up as soon as I try to knit to PDF:

```
Error in !implicit_figures : invalid argument type
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> output_format -> pandoc_options-> from_rmarkdown
Execution halted
```

My YAML header looks like this:

```
 ---
 title: "Surveillance Report"
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{url}
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{helvet}
- \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes8.40  
    includes:
      in_header: PHA_TEST2.tex
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: bmj.csl
---
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\centering{\transparent{0.2} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,     height=\paperheight]{plates2017_lp2.jpg}}%
    }
  }
}
\onehalfspacing
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{PHAlogo.png}}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: try to remove as much as possible to see what's causing the error. is it also happening for other export formats?

Comment: Thanks mb21, it seems the error only occurs when knitting to PDF. It turns out I had accidentally added some paramaters into the YAML header that I did not need. Its has now worked!